# Given the composition of functions $f(g(x))=h(x)$, solve for $f(x)$.

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I know that $f(x)○g(x)=f(g(x))$.

In the case that $$f(g(x))=h(x)$$

then
$$f(x)○g(x)○g(x)^{-1}=h(x)○g(x)^{-1}$$
$$f(x)=h(x)○g(x)^{-1}$$
My question then is how do you then convert out of the composition notation. Would it then be $f(x)=h(g(x)^{-1})$ or maybe $f(x)=g(h(x))^{-1}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be $f(x)=h\big(g^{-1}(x)\big)$. Of course, this is assuming that $g^{-1}(x)$ exists.

It's basically the same as $f(x)\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$. You use the rightmost function as the argument of the leftmost function.

Comment: Good, +1. Note that it's often convenient to drop the argument. So you basically have $$f=(f\circ g)\circ g^{-1}$$ assuming appropriate inverses exist. The notation "$f(x)\circ g(x)$" is not correct. I should really be "$(f\circ g)(x)$".